# Entity Framework can't execute query: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities

I am getting this error when I try to retrieve some data. Here is how I am querying

```
   using (_realtyContext = new realtydbEntities())
   {
                foreach (int yr in years)
                {
                    var standard = (from feest in _realtyContext.FeeStandards
                                    where feest.Year == yr && feest.FeeCategory.CategoryName == "PropertyFee"
                                    select feest).SingleOrDefault();

                    var chargeItem = (from chrgItem in _realtyContext.PropertyFees
                                      where chrgItem.FeeStandardID == standard.FeeStandardID
                                      && chrgItem.HousholdId == Householder.HouseholdID
                                      select chrgItem).SingleOrDefault();

                        this._propertyFees.Add(chargeItem);
                        this._standards.Add(standard);
                }
   }
```

---

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ### the error is on the 2nd query.(var chargeItem)

this query throw an error: **var chargeItem =...**

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Please give your question more meaningful topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.SingleOrDefault() returns null when no records are found, and in the next statement you're using "standard" as if it is never null.

But that's just one of the many possible causes...

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if standard is null. SingleOrDefault() will return null if there are no results